# I cannot understand this question called "Convert an Array Into a 2D Array With Conditions" while solving in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

This question is called "Convert an Array Into a 2D Array With Conditions" and I was trying to solve this question in C. But I cant understand what I have to return and the parameters passed in the function such as what it the use of a pointer called return size and a pointer to a pointer called columnsize.

The question goes like...
**You are given an integer array nums. You need to create a 2D array from nums satisfying the following conditions:

->The 2D array should contain only the elements of the array nums.

->Each row in the 2D array contains distinct integers.

->The number of rows in the 2D array should be minimal.

->Return the resulting array. If there are multiple answers, return any of them.

Note that the 2D array can have a different number of elements on each row.**

And the example are:-

**
Input: nums = [1,3,4,1,2,3,1]

Output: [[1,3,4,2],[1,3],[1]]

Explanation: We can create a 2D array that contains the following rows:

- 1,3,4,2
- 1,3
- 1

All elements of nums were used, and each row of the 2D array contains distinct integers, so it is a valid answer.
It can be shown that we cannot have less than 3 rows in a valid array.**

```
 /*
 * Return an array of arrays of size *returnSize.
 * The sizes of the arrays are returned as *returnColumnSizes array.
 * Note: Both returned array and *columnSizes array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */

int** findMatrix(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes){

}
```

Comment: First, that's not a "2D array".  It's an array of pointers to individual and completely separate 1D arrays.  The use of "2D array" can be confusing.  Second, Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service that you can use to answer your homework questions.  Please post your own code where you've tried to solve the problem yourself, and ask specific questions about problems you're having.

Comment: Well ... the function calculates a lot of things. And it has to return a lot of information. When you need to return a lot of information, basically there are 2 options: group the information inside a `struct` and return a (pointer to the) struct ... or pass pointers into the function and fill the corresponding address with the correct value(s). This `findMatrix()` function opted for the 2nd choice.

Comment: Check the simplified example at https://ideone.com/Ebed1h

Answer (score 1):

> But I cant understand what I have to return and the parameters passed in the function such as what it the use of a pointer called return size and a pointer to a pointer called columnsize.

The parameter `nums` is a pointer to the first element of an array containing the input values.

The parameter `numsSize` is the number of elements in the above array.

The parameter `returnSize` is a pointer to where your function must store the number of rows in the output array.

The parameter `returnColumnSizes` is a pointer to where your function must store the pointer to memory it allocates, and that memory is to contain a sequence of values that are the numbers of elements in the rows of the output “array.” For example, the “array” [[1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 3], [1]] contains three rows containing 4, 2, and 1 elements, so you would set `returnColumnSizes` to point to memory where you had stored the `int` values 4, 2, and 1.

The function return value is a pointer to memory your function allocates, and that memory contains one pointer for each row in the output array. Each of those pointers points to additional memory your function allocates, and, for each pointer, that memory contains the elements of the corresponding row of the output array.

Comment: okay I get some of it but i still have confusion regarding the returncolumnsize pointer.

Comment: so for the given exmaple the returncolumnsize will point at the [1,3,4,2] when its is returned or else we have to make an other array which will store the number of elements in each row like an array [4,2,1] and the returncolumnsize pointer will point at this array

Comment: Maybe it helps if you think about `returnColumnSizes` as an array with the sizes of each respective column: in the calling function `returnColumnSizes[0]` (or whatever the name is inside the calling function) will have the size of the 1st row; `returnColumnSizes[1]` will have the size of the 2nd row, ...